# How does google Translate works as a proxy?

Tags: proxy, google-translate

When you put a link inside the text field in Google Translate, it gives you back the same URL which you can click and then it loads the page in what still seems the inside of Google translate.

How does it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you submit a URL to Google Translate, it displays the same URL as a hyperlink in the translation box, however the actual link is some JavaScript:

```
javascript:ctr._submitUrl(true);
```

This JavaScript performs the redirect to the proxied Google Translate version of the page: `https://translate.google.com/translate?`